# CSS Email styling not working with Outlook

Tags: css, office365, html-email, outlook-web-app

I have a very simple inline css style that works fine everywhere but Outlook (browser version).

I found this [compatibility website](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/text-align/) and according to it, things should work fine.

Code:

```
<footer style="font-size: 9px;text-align: center;">
  <p>
   /.../
  </p>
</footer>
```

Is there a way to achieve this result **also with Outlook?**
I Couldn't find, but anyone know if there is a `preview` for email styling?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Maybe your `<footer>` is removed?

Comment: Hi, @Justinas When we open the email on Outlook, there is no formatting. I checked on `Inspect Element` and you are right. While I have the `<footer>` tag on gmail. It is gone on Outlook. So maybe the solution would be to apply the style to `<p>` tag?

Comment: Don't use fancy HTML5, use simple `<div>` instead of `<footer>`

Comment: Thanks @Justinas that was the answer. Cant use `<footer>`

Answer (score 0):

Use table and write the styles inline in the `table cell(td)` like below and it will work in Outlook.

Many tags and CSS rules don't work for emails but work fine for webpages and emails when checked in browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Email</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

  <!-- using footer -->
  <footer style="font-size: 9px;text-align: center;">
    <p>
     This is inside the footer
    </p>
  </footer>
  
  <!-- using table -->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 9px;text-align: center;">
              This is inside the table
            </td>
          </tr>          
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: I added those meta tags from a XHTML doc. My bad. Thanks for noticing and correcting.